# Wiring diagram - what is the meaning of stacked arrows?

Tags: wiring, diagram

I'm trying to figure out whether the stacked arrows means the conductors are twisted together?

[image: snippet of wiring diagram]

Comment: Totally unclear what this is. Context, please. If someone showed this to me, I'd say it's some kind of weird energy plateau diagram for allowed state of electrons in a lattice or something.

Comment: Is this out of an electric potato peeler schematic or a 5G mobile phone tower?

Comment: I can't share the whole drawing or I would.  It is on the wiring diagram for a military power source.  The blue oval is for shielding.  I think the arrows mean that those particular conductors are twisted together per IPC 620 but have never seen the arrows  FYI - love the comment  of electric potato peeler, i am hungry

Comment: FYI -  my crazy customer says it is for twisting conductors.

Answer (score 2):

Near as I can tell the arrows just mean that the pointed-to conductors are associated.  They don't necessarily have to be twisted.  This is from IEEE Std 315-1975, "Graphic Symbols for Electrical and Electronics Diagrams"

[image]

There's a slightly different symbol for twisted (pairs, triplets, quads, etc).

[image]

Comment: it sure would be nice if customers used industry standard symbols :)

Comment: It takes a concerted effort.  At my company we have a couple of people who's sole purpose is to make ANSI/IEEE compliant symbols for use in schematics, for when the standard vendor supplied symbols are not adequate.